# JS - if hidden field's value is "x," then execute function

Tags: javascript, function, object

I think this is pretty simple, but I am writing 1 JavaScript include that will go on multiple pages with a form. All of the pages have a hidden field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test1">
```

Some pages have the value as "test1," while others have "test2." I only want to execute this script for pages with the "test1" value. I do NOT want it on pages with "test2" value.

For reference, here is the JS:

```
function CheckDay(obj) {
        if (obj.value == "F") {
            document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = "29.99";
        } else {
            document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = "39.99";
        }
    }
```

I'm just not sure how to say, only run if "test" value is "test1". Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you calling the function? What are you passing down to obj?

Comment: This should work already, call it like: `CheckDay(document.getElementsByName("name")[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition in the funnction to execute the javascript only when the value of test is test1 (Or you can call the function CheckDay from another function after checking the value)

```
function CheckDay(obj) {
    if(document.getElementsByName('test')[0].value==='test1'){
        if (obj.value == "F") {
            document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = "29.99";
        } else {
            document.getElementsByName("price")[0].value = "39.99";
        }
    }
}
```